# How to mail a table layout in android

Tags: android, email

I've created a table layout in android which is populated dynamically..There is a button at the bottom of the layout which reads as.." SEND VIA MAIL". Now I want that when I click this button, it should send the data in the table layout to the required email id via yahoomail or gmail...Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have not experience in such app but I think you must have OnClickListener in that button,and within that method(event) you must get all data from your table and after that send email.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that does something similar to this. There are several issues to consider. It is quite a task, but yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this intent in onClickLIstener of that button and pass value to this intent as string variable in the place of datatosend

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "datatoSend");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "sending mail"));
```